# Wronski-Test for linear ODE

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, fundamental-solution

To test solutions of linear ODEs for lineary independence you can determine the wronski determinant. The theorem says if you have a solution to the linear ODE in the form:
$$
\dot{\vec{x}}(t) = A \cdot \vec{x}(t) 
$$
you can test for linear independence by showing
$$\exists t_0 \in I\colon\;
\operatorname{det}(W(t_0)) \neq 0
$$
with $W(x)$ being the Wronski-Matrix:
$$
W(t) = \begin{pmatrix}
\vec{x_1}(t)& \cdots & \vec{x_n}(t)
\end{pmatrix}
$$ where $x_i$ is the i-th vector of the solution.
If you find just one $t_0$ it follows that:
$$\forall t \in I\colon\;\operatorname{det}(W(t)) \not\equiv 0$$
(With $\not\equiv 0$ i mean constant not zero).
I don't understand why this implication holds true.

Why can I conclude from the fact that the Wronski determinant is at one point equal zero that it must be everywhere? $ det (W (t)) $ is not constant and it depends on $t$.

I'm happy about any answers!

Many Greetings,
Sebi2020

Comment: I think the issue is that if the Wronskian determinant is nonzero for some $t_0 \in I$, we are guaranteed that the solutions are linearly independent.  If the solutions were not linearly independent, the Wronskian would always be zero (looking at contrapositive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This matter may be resolved *via* [Liouville's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_formula), which affirms that if $X(t)$ an $n \times n$ matrix solution of the differential equation

$\dot X(t) = A(t)X(t) \tag 1$

the determinant of $\det(X(t))$ of $X(t)$ is given by

$\det(X(t)) = \det(X(t_0)) \exp \left ( \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^t \text{trace}(A(s)) \; ds \right ); \tag 2$

since

$\exp \left ( \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^t \text{trace}(A(s)) \; ds \right ) \ne 0, \; \forall t_0, t \in I, \tag 3$

we see that

$\det(X(t)) \ne 0 \Longleftrightarrow \det(X(t_0)) \ne 0. \tag 4$

Now we may conclude with the simple observation that we may take

$W(t) = \det(X(t)) = \det(\vec x_1(t), \vec x_2(t), \ldots, \vec x_n(t)). \tag 5$

Comment: But is it only a implication from the liouville formula or is there another explanation? Our lecturer said that the reason for this is that the solutions form a vector room. But I cannot explain myself why this should be a proof for $det(X(t)) \neq 0 \Leftrightarrow det(X(t_0))\neq 0$ whereas the liouville formula shows that. I think the vector room property explains only the need to look for solutions which form a fundamental system.

Comment: @Sebi2020:  is a "vector room" the same as a vector space?

Comment: Yes. English is not my native language, so I used the wrong translation for "vector space". But I wanted to say vector space.

Comment: @Sebi2020:  that's OK I got what you meant.

Comment: @Sebi2020:  I think there is in fact another approach based upon uniqueness of solutions; if the $\vec x_i$ are linearly dependent at some point, so that $\sum a_i \vec x_i(t_0) = 0$, then we must have the unique solution $\vec x(t) = \sum a_i \vec x_i(t) = 0$ everywhere, since there is only one solution satisfying $\vec x(t) = 0$.  Then if $\vec x(t_0) \ne 0$, $\vec x(t) \ne 0$, $\forall t$. Then the $\vec x_i(t)$ are linearly independent, so $W(t) \ne 0$.  See what I mean?

Comment: I think I don't quite understand it. I struggle with this: " if the $x_i$ are linearly dependent at some point, so that $\sum a_i x_i(t_0) = 0$, then we must have the unique solution $x(t) = \sum a_ix_i(t) = 0$ everywhere". This is what I dont understand. Which property of linear equations or vector spaces proves that? I would thought that $a_ix_i(t_0)$ maybe resides to $\operatorname{ker} x(t_0)$ but that this dosn't have to be true for $x(t), t\neq0$. Is it just the existence and uniqueness theorem saying that there can only be one solution with $x(t) = 0$?

Comment: @Sebi2020:  I can't read your comment; please fix the $\LaTeX$ and send me a comment when you do. OK now it's better! Thanks. Cheers!

Comment: @Sebi2020:  yes, you got it!  It's just the uniqueness!

Comment: Thank you! Your're explanations were very helpful.

Comment: @Sebi2020:  thanks for the kind words, and of course for the "acceptance".  Cheers!